# Left += Operation for Strings

Tags: python

In Python, the `+=` operation is a [right-action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)#Right_group_action), meaning that `a+=b` is equivalent to `a=a+b`.

Since, for strings, this operation is not commutative, it raises the question if there is a similar operator for a left-action, i.e. some operator (or other hack) say `%=` such that `a%=b` does `a=b+a`?

## Addendum

The solutions so far, except the obvious `a=b+a`, involved overriding the `str.__add__` method which, as pointed out by @BrianJoseph, was not quite what I had in mind since it merely *shifts the problem to the other extreme*.

The following workaround, involving [this amazing hack](http://tomerfiliba.com/blog/Infix-Operators/), illustrates the behaviour I was seeking.

**Prelims**

```
# -------------------------------------------------------------
# Following class can be found in Tomer Filiba's blog
# Link provided in the question
from functools import partial

class Infix(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __or__(self, other):
        return self.func(other)
    def __ror__(self, other):
        return Infix(partial(self.func, other))
    def __call__(self, v1, v2):
        return self.func(v1, v2)
# -------------------------------------------------------------

# Custom Class
class my_str(str):
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string
    def __str__(self):
        return self.string.__str__()
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.string.__repr__()
    @Infix
    def left_assign(self, string):
        self.string = string + self.string
```

**Example**

```
# Testing
a = my_str('World')
b = 'Hello'
print(a)
# World
a |my_str.left_assign| b
print(a)
# HelloWorld
```

Of course the line `a |my_str.left_assign| b` is not exactly easier to write then `a = b + a`, but this was just an example for illustrations.

Finally, for those to whom my non-edited question might have been unclear: I am (was) wondering if `a=b+a` can bone writing `a` just once (analogously to `a+=b` for `a=a+b`).

Comment: No, you will have to do `a=b+a`.

Comment: can you elaborate on your use case?

Comment: Not a thing, but perhaps you can create custom behavior using dunder methods similar to `__rmod__`,`__rmul__`, etc... In the end. It's probably much cleaner to just suck it up and use `a = b + a`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Appending `https` on the left hand side of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking if there's a single operator to prepend strings (instead of appending them like `+=`), I don't think there is one.  Writing out:

```
b = a + b
```

is the most succinct way I know of how to prepend `a` onto `b`.

(Interestingly, because string appending is non-commutative, Larry Wall (the creator of Perl) chose to use `.` as the string-appending operator, so as to leave `+` completely commutative and mathematical, in that `a += b` means both `a = a+b` and `a = b+a`.  Unless you explicitly overload it, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no.

The long answer:

You can create your own class based on `str` and override some operator action.

```
class A(str):
    def __add__(s, st):
        return st + s
```

This one will work as:

```
>>> A(50)
'50'
>>> A(50) + 'abc'
'abc50'
>>> a = A('aaa')
>>> a += 'ccc'
>>> a
'cccaaa'
```

But you definitely will need to learn documentation about overriding "magic" methods such as `__add__` to be sure that you'll implement right behavior, because there is many side-cases in which it could work not ideal in current implementation. For example, current implementation causes RecursionError if both sides is instances of `A` class.

Honestly, all this stuff is not very good practice because it's not about Zen of Python and may be cause of headache of other programmers that will work with this code. So all these things is nothing but interesting just for fun experiments. For real convenient solution see short answer.

P.S.: Of course, you can override some other operator instead of `+`. For example, `__mul__` is for `*`. You can even override bitwise ops such as `<<` and `&`

P.P.S.: The operator that you mentioned, `%=`, really exists. Not much people know about it, but it is a shorthand for `a = a % b`, it's very useful for formatting strings:

```
a = 'Some number: %d; some string: %s'
a %= 1, 'abc'
print(a)
```

Will give you `Some number: 1; some string: abc`

Comment: I don't know if this really answers OPs question. This replaces the built-in functionality of the `+` operator. It's doesn't really add additional functionality. It just shifts the problem to the other extreme

Comment: @BrianJoseph, as I said, the other operator can be overrided. For example, any bitwise operator or maybe divide operator and so on

Comment: Yeah I understand. It just doesn't seem like a complete solution when you have to forfeit the functionality of one of the built-in operators to support a custom one. But your solution might be the best one can reasonably do

Comment: @BrianJoseph one could built a hacky custom operator http://code.activestate.com/recipes/384122/

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such operation. The complete list of operators can be found in the Python language reference, starting at [section 6.5](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator).

Answer (score 0):

You could define another class inheriting from `str`:

```py
class myStr(str):
    def __init__(self, s):
        super(str, s)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return other + self

s = myStr("abc")
print(s) #prints 'abc'

s += "d"
print(s) #prints 'dabc'
```

I don't see any use case frankly, though.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. Read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements). The `+=` is called augmented assignment

It is implemented for the common binary operators in python:`"+=" | "-=" | "*=" | "@=" | "/=" | "//=" | "%=" | "**="| ">>=" | "<<=" | "&=" | "^=" | "|="`

You can change the workings of the augmented assignment operation by changing the way the operation is computed at class level, e.g. in your example:

```
class Foo(str):
    def __add__(s, other):
        return other + s
```

Although I would not recommend it.